# Createjs: Stage.update() internal working question for performance optimization. Does it happen at each tick, or each time it's called?

Tags: createjs, easeljs, stage

In order to optimize createjs code, I cannot find info on this matter.
Case:
I have a scrollbar component, and each time I move the scrollbar stage is updated to reflect changes in scrollbar visual. Also a scroll event is triggered.
Application listens to the event, and updates some visual in scrolled content, therefore another Stage.update() is triggered.

My question is: does stage get updated only at each "tick", or the above situation will cause stage to update twice in the same instant degrading performance?

In code, will:

```
stage.update();
stage.update();
stage.update();
```

Cause stage to update 3 times in a row? Or only once at next tick?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no debouncing on the stage update, so each time you call it, the stage will be rendered. Additionally, internal counters like tick-based frame advances will be fired.

It is not advisable to run it more times than you need to. Usually apps either have a continuous Ticker, or are updated only when content changes.

If you want to create a hybrid, I recommend checking an `update` property that you set yourself. Then you can toggle it any time, and it will run once per tick max.

```
createjs.Ticker.on("tick", function(e) {
  if (shouldUpdate) { stage.update(e); }
  shouldUpdate = false;
});
```

Hope that helps!